# Unable to use pip to install github repo

Tags: github, pip

I am not able to use anymore the pip install command to install from a github branch. I was using this line of code for the last 2 years but suddenly it stoped working:

```
/home/training/bin/pip install git+https://github.com/org/project@my_branch
```

My git version is 1.7.10 and my operating system is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4

The error I get is:

```
  Cloning https://github.com/wfp-ose/django-geoexplorer.git (to wfp_migration_training) to /tmp/pip-jDnC_j-build
  error:  while accessing https://github.com/wfp-ose/django-geoexplorer.git/info/refs

 fatal: HTTP request failed
 Complete output from command /usr/bin/git clone -q https://github.com/wfp-ose/django-geoexplorer.git /tmp/pip-jDnC_j-build:
```

When  I check in the pip log I get:

```
Command /usr/bin/git clone -q https://github.com/wfp-ose/django- 
geoexplorer.git /tmp/pip-jDnC_j-build failed with error code 128 in None
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/training/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 
122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/home/training/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", 
line 278, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, 
bundle=self.bundle)
File "/home/training/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1197, in 
prepare_files
do_download,
File "/home/training/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1360, in 
unpack_url
unpack_vcs_link(link, loc, only_download)
File "/home/training/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 344, 
in unpack_vcs_link
vcs_backend.unpack(location)
File "/home/training/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py", line 
240, in unpack
self.obtain(location)
File "/home/training/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/git.py", line 111, 
in obtain
call_subprocess([self.cmd, 'clone', '-q', url, dest])
File "/home/training/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in 
call_subprocess
% (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/git clone -q https://github.com/wfp- 
ose/django-geoexplorer.git /tmp/pip-jDnC_j-build failed with error code 128 
in 
None
```

I haven't changed anything in my .config file for git and I am logged in properly in my github account.

**EDIT**
I think this is related to this:
https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the text at https://github.com/wfp-ose/django-geoexplorer.git/info/refs:

> Please upgrade your git client.
>   GitHub.com no longer supports git over dumb-http

Comment: What does this mean exactly? I have updated my git client to 3.2.29 but I still get these errors.

Comment: The latest stable release of git is [2.17.1](https://github.com/git/git/releases/tag/v2.17.1), I doubt you can upgrade to 3.2.29.

Comment: Hehe. That sounds funny indeed. I just get the version by: yum git --version: 3.2.29